# Zend Framework 2 project example

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-tool

Can someone give me an Zend Framework 2 project example,
 or any info how to use zend_tool for ZF2.

Thanks

Comment: Try this blog.. Its a code base for zf2 hello world..<http://kdecom.blogspot.co.nz/2012/09/zend-framework-2-hello-world-example.html>

Comment: A new Utility module has been made to fill the need to zend_tool. [https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 is under heavy development right now so there are no real examples yet. You can follow the development of ZF2 on [github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2).

The only ready components we have now are Autoloader and Plugin Loader. You could also [use them in your current ZF applications](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/262-Backported-ZF2-Autoloaders.html).

Answer (score 26):

Best resources which I found so far is :
1. manual http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/index.html
2. Matthew Weier O'phinney 3 articles so far http://mwop.net/blog/tag/zf2  
3. Rob Allen ZF2 book  http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf
4. Nice ZF2 Module base website example: https://github.com/EvanDotPro/MwopGuestbook
5. http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/ - nice tutorial all what you need to setup ZF2-D2

Finaly ZF2 wiki where you can find more resources and for me this is best page from which you can strat learning zf2
http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42303506

Answer (score 7):

For anyone stumbling across this questions as of September 2012; now that Zend have released the first stable version of Zend Framework you can use their skeleton application which takes a few minutes to set up, and takes you through all of the finer details about creating a project.

http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 is still a ways away.  I don't think that the MVC milestone has been completed yet.