# Zend Framework 2 for a Zend Framework Newbie

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'd like to use ZF2 for an upcoming project. However, I find it really hard to understand the few tutorials that I've found out there. Most of them just tell you to put stuff in files without really explaining what everything is or any other option I may have.

Is there any book or tutorial for an absolute zf beginner?

---

Well, I started using Yii until ZF2 is released.

Yii has just amazed me. In two days I've been able to start building something. It is dead simple, yet powerful. They have great documentation and the framework is very easy to understand and use if you have a good knowledge of MVC and SQL. The documentation on their site is also very good. There are tutorials for absolute beginners. That I liked.
Zend may be a more robust and powerful framework, but it's tediously painful to learn. It lacks the simplicity of Yii. I went nuts trying to understand all those configuration lines.

I followed every tutorial recommended in this thread for two weeks and gave up. Telling someone to just enter some code without explaining what it means or how it can be tweaked is not a good way to teach and promote a framework.
I'll pick up ZF2 when it's released. I hope they make it friendlier. I hope the documentation also improves and goes from simple to complex examples. I really want to learn the ZF.

Comment: Akrabat is your best bet, otherwise just read the framework.

Comment: That's the tutorial I tried to follow. It basically tells you to put this an that, here and there. It doesn't really explain much. I guess it would've been easier if I knew ZF1 to begin with, but it doesn't make sense to learn it now when version 2 will be out soon.

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2012/04/17/zend-framework-2-concepts-flexibility-complexity/) that addresses some of this.

Comment: you're to early for that kind of documentation for ZF2, we have a bit of a wait yet until us newbies are going to be able to tackle this one. Even the official documentation is incomplete.

Comment: I don't think that ZF2 is at a useable stage yet, there is still a lot of functionality missing. Remember, it hasn't reached beta yet. I would say, that at the moment, it is for experienced developers only and probably not them.

Comment: It's actually at Beta3, http://packages.zendframework.com/

Comment: Zend Framework 2 I think is different from Zend Framework 1, the tutorial from Akrabat is a very different approach if you compared it to the early version of ZF.

The author approach a test driven development techqnique in building controller in ZF2. And on regarding the configuration , I think it is a bit hard to understand at first.

Comment: Why was this closed? These sorts of questions seem to get closed a lot, which to my mind is plain dogmatism. This question, which perhaps not asked very well, has some pretty useful answers. StackOverflow is not a religion, stop acting as though it is.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are a number of articles you could read that could help:

- [Official documentation](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/index.html) - has useful stuff - especially the view quick start
- [View Layers, Database Abstraction, Configuration, Oh, My!](http://mwop.net/blog/zf2-beta3.html) - Good intro to View Layer & Db
- [Getting started writing ZF2 modules](http://mwop.net/blog/267-Getting-started-writing-ZF2-modules.html) - Good intro to modules
- [Modules in ZF2](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/modules-in-zf2/) - Another intro to modules
- [Using the ZF2 EventManager](http://mwop.net/blog/266-Using-the-ZF2-EventManager.html) - introduction to event manager
- [PHP Constructor Best Practices And The Prototype Pattern](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern) - Zend\Db\ResultSet uses this
- [Using the ServiceManager as an Inversion of Control Container](http://techblog.shinymayhem.com/2013/09/using-servicemanager-as-inversion-of.html) - How to use Zend\ServiceManager
- [Zend\ServiceManager configuration keys](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/zendservicemanager-configuration-keys/) - Useful Zend\ServiceManager information

Also, these blog categories have useful info:

- Matthew Weier O'Phinney's [ZF2 articles](http://mwop.net/blog/tag/zf2.html)
- Rob Allen's [ZF2 articles](http://akrabat.com/category/zend-framework-2/)
- Matthew Setter's [Master Zend Framework](http://www.masterzendframework.com/blog-archive/)

Books:

- Slavey Karadzhov's [Learn ZF2](http://learnzf.com/book/)
- Matthew Setter's [Zend Framework 2 for Beginners](https://leanpub.com/zendframework2-for-beginners)

For source code:

- http://modules.zendframework.com/
- https://github.com/akrabat/ZF2TestApp

Answer (score 2):

Rob Allen ZF2 tutorial is now part of the official docs: http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/user-guide/overview.html

Also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894828/760703

Comment: Rob Allen's official tutorial is useful, but you have to read all the comments below it as errors are not corrected. Its also difficult to follow because the project has been given the same name as one of the objects (Album).
I'm also unclear as to why some things are in lower case (album/album/) and which things are 'System' - i.e. Zend\Db\Adaptor\Adaptor.