# Is there a good basic overview of zend framework 2 anywhere?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've been through loads of tutorials, etc on Zend Framework 2 but I can't seem to find a single general overview which describes the base components and logic flow in a simplistic manner.

All tutorials available at the moment seem to make huge assumptions and simply give code examples that solve specific problems without going into the fundamental ideas behind them. The ZF2 documentation is the main culprit for this.

This is the most useful thing I've found for a general overview although this is out-dated now: http://zendframework2.de/en/cheat-sheet.html

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It is not as outdated as you may think. Since beta5 there haven't been any critical BC breaks as far as i can remember. Other than that there's pretty much only the official documentation.

Comment: Have a look at this SO Posting  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137021/zend-framework-2-project-example Lookinto the answer posted by @NikSen

Comment: There's also this one created by Evan Coury, but also out of date: http://tinyurl.com/zf2-dispatch-process

Comment: Thanks all, some good stuff here. Still, all of it is quite complex. There must be something simple somewhere! I'm looking for a *eureka* moment when all the ideas behind the framework click into place and I 'get it'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to go and read about Zend Framework 2 is the ZF2's manual of course.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/index.html

I would also recommend you to follow the webinars at the Zend website that are related to ZF2

http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework

BLOGS:

Matthew Weier O'Phinney is the lead developer of the ZF2 project and kind of the guy that know everything in ZF2. He has a blog where he shares interesting talks, concepts and ideas related to ZF2 and PHP.
http://www.mwop.net/

Even Coury is a contributor to the ZF2 and the creator of the ModuleManager. He has some great modules on his github and blog that are to be followed :)
http://blog.evan.pro/

Ralph Schindler is anothe contributors to the ZF2 that has a blog and often post cool things and concepts about zf2
http://ralphschindler.com/

**EDIT** for the blogs part:

I recently found out that the framework.zend.com website provides a list of the contributors of the project. This list provides information about the github accounts and the blogs of those contributors (if they have stated any). Looking there you can also find useful resources about ZF2. Here is the link:

http://framework.zend.com/participate/contributors

And there is one guy Alexander Romanenko that makes a you tube seria about ZF2 application development. He touches on a lot of aspects and important components of the ZF2. Right now there are 9 videos where he starts building application taking into consideration a lot of things related to day-to-day web development

https://www.youtube.com/feed/UCLgC6BIGw2brdJK7Lb4elpg

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Stoyan very useful, particularly the Alexander Romanenko youtube channel

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful:
http://zf2cheatsheet.com

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the "Using Zend Framework 2" book available here:
https://leanpub.com/using-zend-framework-2